# Connecting to ftp server

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

I am trying to connect to multilple ftp servers using `ftp_connect` and `ftp_login`. My code is very simple as given

```
 foreach ($ftp_accounts as $ftp_account) {
     $connect_id = $ftp_account['server'];
                $user = $ftp_account['user'];
                $pass = $ftp_account['password'];
                echo 'Ftp Server: '.$connect_id.'<br> Username: '.$user. '<br> Password: '.$pass.'<br>';
                if (ftp_login($connect_id, $user, $pass)){
                    echo "| Connected to server " . $connect_id . " as " . $user . '<br>';
                } else {
                    echo "Couldn't connect to $connect_id as $user \n";
                }
 }
```

I have a table in my database with multiple servers and their credentials. but the code i wrote give me the following error (warning) message

```
 ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given
```

and it goes to the else statement for every server.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer my question. First of all the replies I get was all corect options to be checked for such problems I highly appriciate the replies but one thing you also need to check is that wether your server firelwall allows to connect to any outgoing ftp server or not ?
If it does not allow you to connect then even with everything written correct in your code you will not be able to connect to the server. So before testing your code check your server firewall settings.

It worked for me when i allowed all outgoing connections.

Once again Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ftp_connect()` to connect to the server before trying to login. Additionally, you need to check the result of `ftp_connect()` to ensure it was able to connect before you try to login. If it wasn't then it returns `FALSE` and you should **not** proceed to try and login.

```
foreach ($ftp_accounts as $ftp_account) {
     $connect_id = ftp_connect($ftp_account['server']);

    if($connect_id !== false)
    {

       $user = $ftp_account['user'];
       $pass = $ftp_account['password'];
       echo 'Ftp Server: '.$connect_id.'<br> Username: '.$user. '<br> Password: '.$pass.'<br>';
       if (ftp_login($connect_id, $user, $pass)){
             echo "| Connected to server " . $connect_id . " as " . $user . '<br>';
          } else {
             echo "Couldn't connect to $connect_id as $user \n";
        } 
    } else {
       echo 'failed to connect to server';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<?php
$connect_id = $ftp_account['server'];
?>
```

with

```
<?php
$connect_id = ftp_connect($ftp_account['server']);
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: now it gives this warning ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: This means your code is not able to connect to `$ftp_account['server']`. Check whether you can connect to this server via ftp clients like WinSCP.

Comment: can I use filezilla ftp client to chck it ?

Comment: sure, if you comfortable with that.

Comment: I checked it using filezilla client and I can connect to the servers successfully :(

Comment: hmm, in your code, are all the ftp connections failing...or for only a few servers.

Comment: all are failing actually The $connect_id return false. I am using localhost is it possible to connect any ftp using localhost?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11007/discussion-between-pushpesh-and-faryal-khan)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to make connection to server using [`ftp_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php) function, assuming that in variable `$ftp_account['server']` you have valid FTP server host address.

```
foreach ($ftp_accounts as $ftp_account) {
    $connect_id = ftp_connect($ftp_account['server']);
    if ($connect_id === false) {
        echo "Failed to connect to FTP server";
        continue;
    }
    $user = $ftp_account['user'];
    $pass = $ftp_account['password'];
    echo 'Ftp Server: ' . $ftp_account['server'] . '<br> Username: ' . $user . '<br> Password: ' . $pass . '<br>';
    if (ftp_login($connect_id, $user, $pass)){
        echo "| Connected to server " . $ftp_account['server'] . " as " . $user . '<br>';
    } else {
        echo "Couldn't connect to " . $ftp_account['server'] . " as " . $user . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives this warning message ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: @FaryalKhan It happens because `ftp_connect` is unable to connect to FTP server and returns `false`. Possibly the host address is invalid. Try the updated version of the code. It checks for this error.

Comment: $connect_id returns false for every server

Comment: @FaryalKhan Check the `port` argument. By default it uses 21, possibly you need another (i.e. 22).

Comment: but I can connect to all servers using filezilla client without any port